# Installed using apt-get, then ran out of storage

Tags: apt, aptitude, dpkg

I attempted to install a large package, forgetting that I had little space left, and now I am a little stuck.

When I attempt to remove any packages I get the following error:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

And when I run the dpkg command, it complains I have no space. Is there a way I can explicitly tell it to abort installing, or free up the space (preferably without manually deleting package manager files).

Answer (score 4):

sudo apt-get clean

resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to install a gigantic 12-GB package (`intel-basekit`, a part of intel-oneapi) on an AWS instance with only 8GB of disk.

`sudo apt-get clean` didn't give me enough disk space to do `apt --fix-broken install`.

Luckily I had 15GB of memory. I moved away `/opt` (where the packages were installed), mounted the extra memory under `/opt` as a ramdisk, and moved everything into the new ramdisk-ed `/opt`. This allowed me to `apt --fix-broken install` to fix the state of the system, then run

```
sudo apt purge intel-basekit
sudo apt autoremove
```

To undo my mistake.

Just in case you're panicking like me, try [ramdisks](https://linuxhint.com/ramdisk_ubuntu_1804/).